# Process32Next different results

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm doing a code to scan another process memory. But that's not the question here. To list the processes running I'm using Process32First/Process32Next. But when I'm running it inside the compiler debug it get all processes (including other users like system processes)
but when I just ran the .exe, only get the processes from my user. The stretch of the code is below

```
 Handle:= CreateToolHelp32SnapShot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
 Struct.dwSize:=Sizeof(TProcessEntry32);
 Process32First(Handle, Struct);
   repeat
    Memo2.Lines.Append(Struct.szExeFile);
    MemStart:= 0;
    PID:= Struct.th32ProcessID;
    PIDHandle:= OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or
                            PROCESS_VM_READ, false, PID);
    if OS64 = true then
     begin
      if IsProcWow64 then
       begin
        Proc32:= true;
      end
     else
       Proc32:= false;
  end;
 if (Proc32 = true) and (POS(Struct.szExeFile, Application.ExeName) = 0) then
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Append('Process:: '+Struct.szExeFile+' - Scanning');
        CatchYa(Struct.szExeFile);
      end;
  CloseHandle(PIDHandle);
until (not Process32Next(Handle,Struct));
```

As you can see I'm checking for 64-bit processes, because I only want 32-bit.

Comment: I assume your question is about why you get different results. You forgot to say.

Answer (score 3):

You're running the IDE with administrative privileges, and your program inherits those permissions when you start from the debugger.

Unless your program needs administrative privileges, you shouldn't need to run the IDE elevated, either. It should be able to run as a normal user, and then your program will get the same list it does when you run it by itself.

Comment: I tried to run my .exe with admin privileges, but still getting different results.

Comment: @user1526124 We can't see your screen and you don't tell us the difference in output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only initialize proc32 when os64 is true.

Comment: No, on form.create I check if the OS is 64bits. If not, I set the Proc32 var as true and if yes, I set the OS64 as true. The procedure I paste here, just change the Proc32 var if OS is 64... If not, it don't get in the 'if' and don't change the Proc32. So continue trues anyway.